# How to explain a study change in your CV?

Tags: resume, education

I started a master program in IT one year ago, which was supposed to end in 2014. 
Realizing that it was not really heading anywhere, I recently switched to another one in the same general field (Computer Science before, Social Media & Web Technologies now). I feel much better now and am confident that the rest of my studies will go as planned, the only problem being that I will graduate in 2015 instead of the expected 2014. How do I handle that on my resumé?

Do I:

- Write "2012 - 2013: Master in Computer Science, 2013 - 2015: Master in SMWT", probably adding some note to mention that I didn't actually get the first degree;
- Ignore last year, going straight from my 2009 - 2012 bachelor to my 2013 - 2015 master;
- Regroup both master under the same line, as in "2012 - 2015: Master in SMWT";
- Some other solution?

Answer (score 6):

Forget about the year you started and just list the year(s) you graduated [1]:

> MS. in SMWT (2015), BS. in CS (2012)

Also, have a good answer ready, in case someone asks about it in an interview.  Saying that you started out in one are, but then saw that "it wasn't a good fit for me" and at the same time you became interested in this other area, and so you then "took the initiative" and switched, that should be fine.

[1] As mentioned in the answers to a previous post: [How could I explain a 2 year gap in obtaining a degree due to dropping out and then returning?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/how-could-i-explain-a-2-year-gap-in-obtaining-a-degree-due-to-dropping-out-and-t?rq=1)

Comment: Yep, this is the answer. I get a lot of CVs to look at and it's rather uncommon to see anything other than a year of graduation in the education section. People do such a mix of full-time and part-time study these days that the number of years taken to gain a degree really isn't particularly relevant or interesting.