# Gap Year on CV/Resume and Job Advice

Tags: resume, new-job

**My Situation**

Web Dev, University Student. -- currently not enrolled for the second year of my course until I pass an exam which I'm retaking in May. Not entirely sure If i'm going to but I've got until September and want to build upon my experience and generate some income.

On my CV I mentioned that I'm on a Gap Year because i don't know what else to put. Though I feel as if employers see this they'll more than likely not consider taking me on as most will want someone long term and someone who has graduated..

-- Any advice on what I should include ? or the best option on which route i should take..

Regards

Comment: Is there anything different than [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1562/2322)? THey seem nearly identical.

Comment: You may find the only job you can get with no experience and degree are temporary contract jobs of less than a year.

Comment: @Joe Strazzere Its a Year out of studies. But technically that's not what I'm on I failed to pass an exam which caused me to fail the year. So I'm kind of stuck on what i should put..